# GridView in ASP.NET in VB language

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

i am a beginner with Visual Studio and i would like to make a WebForm with GridView. I need to connect my GridView to the SQL server. My issue is that i was told to follow the steps of the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZIOI136IKY

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERHsq.png)

but when i open Visual Studio -> “ASP.Net Web Application” -> WebForms, a Webform surface does not open, all i see is the following screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT31W.png)

Here i don't understand how to open a form surface like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diGXS.png)

I am looking for this surface because the tutorial i should be able to follow also has something similar, where theres the "Form" in the middle and there's toolbox.

Can someone please help me what am i doing wrong? how to get to this surface?

Thank you so much please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: When you create an `empty` asp.net web application, you should add webform(s) yourself. Open `Solution Explorer` tool window, right click on your project, select `Add`, then select `Web Form` and assign the name of web form to create it.

Comment: you saved my life thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

The picture of the form you show is a windows desktop one (so that is NOT web based development).

The choice you are looking for when you create a new project is this one:

[image]

Now you can choose a working site template, or start out 100% empty (I recommend you start with a template).

So, from above, then this:

[image]

And then this:

[image]

Note how I selected authentication drop down = none, and un-checked the configure for https.

Now, UNLIKE DESKTOP land, web land development DOES NOT START with a blank ready to use form. You MUST add the web form FIRST and then you have a design surface.

So, from above, you see/get this:

[image]

However, be it desktop, or web land you THEN have to add the web form, so you right click on the project, and choose "add new item".

e.g., this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot i really appreciate the help, i succeeded